# excel not responding on mouse click

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have been struggling with a strange thing in MS Excel 2010 xlsx file.
Excel works just fine with workbooks except one:

Excel freezes when on mouse click on cell.
This is a sheet-specific thing, because when I delete sheet, the thing is gone.
Also keyboard navigation arrows work as expected.

I've deleted all data, content, text from this worksheet, however it keeps freezing when I click on specific column.

I've checked also macros in dev tab, => all is clear
Also there are no any data connections etc...

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to really be a programming question at all... If there are no special macros just copy the data to a different column.

Answer (score 0):

that sheet might have all cells formatting

1.select all cells

2.clear all formatting

3. save and close it[image]